# How to order in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sql-order-by

I have very complex code. I'm developing a web application for many restaurants where people can order online. I have two tables and models for `Order`, which contains information about `User`, and `OrderDetails` which has `MenuItems`. I created `ShoppingCartController` which has a `ProcessOrder` action

```
public ActionResult ProcessOrder(FormCollection frc)
{
        List<Cart> lstCart = (List<Cart>)Session[strCart];

        Order order = new Order()
        {
            Name = frc["Name"],
            UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
            OrderTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            PaymentType = "Cash",
            Status = "Processing"
        };

        db.Orders.Add(order);
        db.SaveChanges();

        foreach (Cart cart in lstCart)
        {
            OrderDetail orderDetail = new OrderDetail()
            {
                OrderId = order.Id,
                MenuId = cart.Menu.Id,
                Quantity = cart.Quantity,
                Price = cart.Menu.Price,
                RestaurantId = cart.Menu.RestaurantId
            };

            db.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        Session.Remove(strCart);

        return View("OrderSuccess");
}
```

Also I created an `OrderController` for displaying list of orders:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? restaurantId = null)
{
    var orders = db.Orders.Include(o => o.User)
                          .Include(p => p.OrderDetails)
                          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);
    return View(orders.ToList());
}
```

Here I just added `restaurantId` parameter.

And now I want to display orders by `RestaurantId`. I thought about taking `RestaurantId` from `OrderDetails->Menu->RestaurantId`, but I don't think that it works because `OrderDetails` of each order can have many `RestaurantId`.

Should I add `RestaurantId` column in `Order` table? Can you suggest an approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order detail has both orderId and RestaurantId thats the table you need to query from!

Comment: Thank you) I need this kin of advice. I'm sorry if my question was stupid)